# Signalr server miss some call the client method

Tags: silverlight, signalr, signalr-hub, signalr.client

I am using SignalR v1.1.3 and Silverlight v5 in LongPolling.

I have an issue with the server calling methods on the client. The last call either takes a very long time (near 2 minutes) or is simply ignored

1st case : Last call takes 2s

```
public void TestMethod(){
   Clients.Caller.OnTestMethod();
   Clients.Caller.OnTestMethod();
}
```

1st call is immediate, the 2nd one start immediatly too but takes 2 minutes to be catch by the client.

Fiddler output (2nd column show elapsed time) : https://i.stack.imgur.com/BFQi4.png

2nd case : One call takes 2s, One is missed

```
public void TestMethod(){
   Clients.Caller.OnTestMethod();
   Clients.Caller.OnTestMethod();
   Clients.Caller.OnTestMethod();
   Clients.Caller.OnTestMethod();
}
```

First two call are "fast", the Third takes 2s and the last one was never sent

Fiddler output (2nd column show elapsed time) : https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yj1fw.png

Last case : Last call takes 2s

```
public void TestMethod(){
   Clients.Caller.OnTestMethod();
   Clients.Caller.OnTestMethod();
   Clients.Caller.OnTestMethod();
   Thread.Sleep(50);
   Clients.Caller.OnTestMethod();
}
```

Adding a sleep before the last one allowed the call to be done.

Fiddler output (2nd column show elapsed time) : https://i.stack.imgur.com/O7p0Y.png

The code on the client is

```
await hubProxy.Invoke("TestMethod");
```

*** EDIT ***

on the client I have a service which create a hubproxy for every hub found on the server :

```
    public MyHubConnection()
    {
        _hubConnection = new HubConnection(ApplicationHelpers.GetServerRootUri()) {TraceLevel = TraceLevels.All, TraceWriter = Console.Out};
        _hubConnection.Error += ErrorFns.HandleError;
    }

    public async Task StartAsync()
    {
        var time = DateTime.Now;

        var manager = new EntityManager(); 
        var serverHubs = (List<string>)await manager.InvokeServerMethodAsync("Common.SignalRServices, Common", "GetServerHubs");

        foreach (var serverHub in serverHubs)
        {
            _hubRepository[serverHub] = _hubConnection.CreateHubProxy(serverHub);
        }

        await _hubConnection.Start(new LongPollingTransport());
    }

    public IHubProxy GetHubProxy(string hubName)
    {
        if (!_hubRepository.ContainsKey(hubName))
            throw new Exception(string.Format("No hub named '{0}'", hubName));

        return _hubRepository[hubName];
    }
```

I have no idea what's going on ... any clue ?

Answer (score 0):

Our client has an issue with Silverlight using the SSE transport (https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/issues/763). Try using longpolling and see if it fixes your issue.

Comment: I already was using LongPolling (I edited my first post) as you can see.  I updated the project to the v2-RC1 and the issue is still there.  I noticed one thing, once the last (no missed) poll goes into the pending state, asking the server to call again the method on the caller immedialty stop the pending one. Then the new call goes into the pending state for 2min

Comment: Any other suggestion ?

Comment: File an issue with the repro project and we'll take a look at it.